# How to write IF SQL statement in C# for retrieving values from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have these three columns in UI. In dropdown I have a `AllRecords` and some other field. I select that `AllRecords` field and I enter start and end date details.

Now I write a query for that for retrieving the values.

When he select `AllRecords`, depending upon start and end dates, it have to display OR retrieve the data from database table.

I have written a query if the user will select other values, it looks like this ,

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
string queryStr = "SELECT Day,Date,Name,Task,Hours from TaskManualDetails where Date between '"
    + DateTime.Parse(txtStartDate.Text).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
    + "' and '"
    + DateTime.Parse(txtEndDate.Text).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
    + "' and Name ='"
    + DropDownList1.Text.ToString()
    + "'";
SqlDataAdapter s1 = new SqlDataAdapter(queryStr, conn);
s1.Fill(dt);
```

Now the problem is I have to write query for `AllRecords`.

Comment: Does the query written above bring you back any records when you execute it in SQL Management studio?  A tip on formatting your sql query.  Try string queryStr = string.format("SELECT Day,Date,Name,Task,Hours from TaskManualDetails where Date between '{0}' and '{1}' and Name = '{2}'",DateTime.Parse(txtStartDate.Text).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), DateTime.Parse(txtEndDate.Text).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),DropDownList1.Text.ToString());

Comment: Have you heard of **sql parameters**??

Comment: Not really issue-related, but I believe ASP.NET has a datepicker control you could use instead of textboxes for dates.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            string queryStr = "SELECT Day,Date,Name,Task,Hours from TaskManualDetails ";

            if ( DropDownList1.Text.ToString() != "AllRecords")
            queryStr=queryStr+" where Date between '" + DateTime.Parse(txtStartDate.Text).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "' and '" + DateTime.Parse(txtEndDate.Text).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")  + "'"+" and Name ='" + DropDownList1.Text.ToString() + "'";
            SqlDataAdapter s1 = new SqlDataAdapter(queryStr, conn);
            s1.Fill(dt);
```

Only a small change in your query

You have to append **and Name ='" + DropDownList1.Text.ToString()**  to the query only if its not **AllRecords**

Comment: In dropdown I Have a "All Records" Fields.When User  will select that one .He want see this details "SELECT Day,Date,Name,Task,Hours from TaskManualDetails".  the Problem is how can I check that He entered allrecords in dropdown. For that i want to write SQL query.

Comment: @VenkateshChittepu: I have updated my query.. you can find whether he has selected "All records" by using this condition DropDownList1.Text.ToString() == "AllRecords"

Comment: I smell SQL Injection, I agree that you are just following the authors code, but it would be better if you can use parameters and improve the code

Answer (score 0):

Be care about SQL Injection. Use SQLParameter like this:

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter s1 = new SqlDataAdapter();
    s1.SelectCommand.Connection = conn;
    string queryStr = "SELECT Day,Date,Name,Task,Hours from TaskManualDetails WHERE Date BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate";
    s1.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("StartDate", DateTime.Parse(txtStartDate.Text).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
    s1.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("EndDate", DateTime.Parse(txtEndDate.Text).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));

    if (DropDownList1.Text.ToString() != "AllRecords")
    {
        queryStr = queryStr + "  AND Name = @Name";
        s1.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Name", DropDownList1.Text.ToString());
    }

    s1.SelectCommand.CommandText = queryStr;

    s1.Fill(dt);
```